# Magento2: How to create a PDF in a custom module

Tags: magento2, pdf

I would like to generate a custom pdf upon sale and attach it to the sales email all within a custom module.

I think I need to extend `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf` to generate the pdf but I am not certain.

Has anyone done this before or has any idea if I'm on the right track?

// edit:

As per the comments, here is a basic layout as to how I included http://www.fpdf.org/ into my custom module:

First I downloaded the fpdf package. I extracted the files and placed them all into my Modules `Helper` folder, which now looks like this:

`- Helper
 -- font (folder)
 -- makefont (folder)
 -- FPDF.php
 -- Data.php`

`Data.php` is the only file I already had in this folder as it contains my helper Data class.

Next I edited the FPDF.php and added my modules namespace to it.

I edited my helper `Data.php` file and use my namespaces FPDF class:

```
use Company\ModuleName\Helper\FPDF as FPDF;
```

I defined any pdf infos I need in the data Class - you do not need this:

```
// PDF INFOS
protected $pdfFileDir = 'someDir/someSubDir/';
protected $logo1 = 'myLogo.jpg';
protected $logo2 = 'myExtraLogo.jpg';


/**
 * @var \Company\ModuleName\Helper\FPDF
 */
protected $_pdf;
```

and construct it

```
/**
 * @param \Company\ModuleName\Helper\FPDF $pdf
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    (...)
    FPDF $pdf,
    (...)
    array $data = []
) {
    (...)
    $this->_pdf = $pdf;
    (...)
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

I then created my method and generate the pdf:

```
public function generatePdf($productId, $someOtherVars)
{
    #start the pdf
    $pdf = new FPDF();

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(0, 5);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);

    // do your FPDF stuff here
    // eg: $pdf->Cell('', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', 'Page Header Title'), 0, 1);

    // $pdf->Ln(8);
    // $pdf->Cell('', '', $today, 0, 1, 'L');
    // and so forth .. see the FPDF documentation

    // render pdf
    $filename = 'somename' . $productId . '.pdf';
    $pdf->Output($this->getPdfBaseDir() . $filename, 'F');

    return $this->getPdfBaseDir() . $filename;
}
```

Then you call your method in your controller via your helper (which you need to include of course):

`$this->dataHelper->generatePdf($yourVars);`

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: I didn't go that route after all. I tried but in the end it seemed too complex to try and use the AbstractPdf class. I ended up including FPDF with my module (in the Helper) and used it to generate the pdf files. http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: Brilliant. Did you consider dompdf?

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: I did, but one reason as to why I didn't use it was that I didn't want to have to render the html first and then have to render the html into the pdf. There were other reasons too, but I can not recall what they were. For your use it may be better, but only you can decide that.

Comment: Hello, any updates on this question. I am trying to generate PFD for my custom module- Magento2.

Comment: Hi @tecjam can you drop the steps how did you use fpdf library in magento 2.I am trying to include fpdf but not able to do that.Please help me

Comment: @shankarboss: I've edited my Question with my code. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, Working fine @techjam (y)

Comment: For information, you can use this tool to convert HTML to PDF : http://www.html2pdf.fr/en/default and anyway, why use an external dependencies when you can use the built-in with Magento 2?

Comment: @FranckGarnier All this was answered in the comments above: First off, I didn't want to render html to pdf. Why would I want to render html first only to convert it to pdf? Secondly I found it easier to use FPDF rather than using magento 2s AbstractPdf class. This solution worked for me and my problem, clearly it won't be a solution for everybody.

Comment: Ok useful approach so.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153080/magento-2-convert-html-code-into-pdf-file-and-download
http://webkul.com/blog/generate-pdf-string-magento-2-0/

Answer (score 2):

You can use FPDF or TCPDF for creating PDF.

Try to run one of the following command from M2 root directory

> `composer require setasign/fpdf:1.8.1`

It will add fpdf library in vendor folder as setasign/fpdf. Once fpdf install you can use FPDF in you custom module for creating PDF.

$pdf= new \FPDF();

OR

> `composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf`

It will add tcpdf library in vendor folder as tecnickcom/tcpdf.
Once tcpdf install you can use TCPDF in you custom module for creating PDF.

> $pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT,
>   true, 'UTF-8', false);

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Zend_Loader;

class GetPdfData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $dir;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->initializePDF();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $pdfData = [];
        $pdfData["body_data"] = "<h1><b>TEST Data</b></h1>";
        $config = [
            'mode' => 'utf-8',
            'format' => 'A4',
            'default_font_size' => 10,
            'default_font' => "dejavusans",
            'margin_left' => 1.5,
            'margin_right' => 1.5,
            'margin_top' => 1.5,
            'margin_bottom' => 1.5,
            'allow_charset_conversion' => true,
            'orientation' => 'P',
            'showBarcodeNumbers' => false,
            'tempDir' => $this->dir->getPath('var'),
        ];
        $pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($config);
        $pdf->WriteHTML(html_entity_decode($pdfData["body_data"]));
        $outputData = $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I'); // D , F , S
    }

    /**
     * Initialization of mpdf library
     */
    protected function initializePDF()
    {
        error_reporting(0);

        $path = $this->dir->getRoot() . "/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/";

        $this->pdf = $path . 'Mpdf.php';

        //include_once $this->pdf;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pdf, null, true);

        $this->config = $path . 'Config/ConfigVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->config;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->config, null, true);

        $this->ucdn = $path . 'Ucdn.php';

        // require_once $this->ucdn;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->ucdn, null, true);

        $this->defaultCss = $path . 'Css/DefaultCss.php';

        // require_once $this->defaultCss;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->defaultCss, null, true);

        $this->sizeConvertor = $path . 'SizeConverter.php';

        // require_once $this->sizeConvertor;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->sizeConvertor, null, true);

        $this->colorconverter = $path . 'Color/ColorConverter.php';

        // require_once $this->colorconverter;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->colorconverter, null, true);

        $this->gradient = $path . 'Gradient.php';

        // require_once $this->gradient;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->gradient, null, true);

        $this->tableOfContents = $path . 'TableOfContents.php';

        // require_once $this->tableOfContents;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->tableOfContents, null, true);

        $this->cache = $path . 'Cache.php';

        // require_once $this->cache;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->cache, null, true);

        $this->fontCache = $path . 'Fonts/FontCache.php';

        // require_once $this->fontCache;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->fontCache, null, true);

        $this->fontsFileFinder = $path . 'Fonts/FontFileFinder.php';

        // require_once $this->fontsFileFinder;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->fontsFileFinder, null, true);

        $this->cssManager = $path . 'CssManager.php';

        // require_once $this->cssManager;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->cssManager, null, true);

        $this->otl = $path . 'Otl.php';

        // require_once $this->otl;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->otl, null, true);

        $this->form = $path . 'Form.php';

        // require_once $this->form;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->form, null, true);

        $this->hyphenator = $path . 'Hyphenator.php';

        // require_once $this->hyphenator;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->hyphenator, null, true);

        $this->tag = $path . 'Tag.php';

        // require_once $this->tag;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->tag, null, true);

        $this->namedcolors = $path . 'Color/NamedColors.php';

        // require_once $this->namedcolors;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->namedcolors, null, true);

        $this->pageformat = $path . 'PageFormat.php';

        // require_once $this->pageformat;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pageformat, null, true);

        $this->fontVariables = $path . 'Config/FontVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->fontVariables;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->fontVariables, null, true);

        $this->textvars = $path . 'Css/TextVars.php';

        // require_once $this->textvars;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->textvars, null, true);

        $this->border = $path . 'Css/Border.php';

        // require_once $this->border;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->border, null, true);

        $this->logcontext = $path . 'Log/Context.php';

        // require_once $this->logcontext;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->logcontext, null, true);

        $this->ttfontfile = $path . 'TTFontFile.php';

        // require_once $this->ttfontfile;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->ttfontfile, null, true);

        $this->destination = $path . 'Output/Destination.php';

        // require_once $this->destination;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->destination, null, true);

        $this->mpdfexception = $path . 'MpdfException.php';

        // require_once $this->mpdfexception;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->mpdfexception, null, true);

        $this->metricsgenerator = $path . 'Fonts/MetricsGenerator.php';

        // require_once $this->metricsgenerator;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->metricsgenerator, null, true);

        $this->GlyphOperator = $path . 'Fonts/GlyphOperator.php';

        // require_once $this->GlyphOperator;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->GlyphOperator, null, true);

        $this->barcode = $path . 'Barcode.php';

        // require_once $this->barcode;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->barcode, null, true);

    }

}
```

**Note: MPdf is installing via composer require mpdf/mpdf command which placed into the vendor directory.**

Answer (score 0):

**Magento2: How to create a PDF in a custom module**

```
public function execute()
{
    $file = $this->getRequest()->getParam('file');

    if(isset($file) && !empty($file)) {

        $pdf = \Zend_Pdf::load($this->directory_list->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
        $fileName = test.pdf;
        $this->fileFactory->create(
        $fileName,
        str_replace('/Annot /Subtype /Link', '/Annot /Subtype /Link /Border[0 0 0]', $pdf->render()),
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
        'application/pdf'
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **You Can Check Below Link**

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ORs80r5okZoWdQqLi1gJtlUZ6UH4luBs1SN0YRioiD0/edit

**app/code/VendoreName/RmaPdfPrint/Controller/Rma**

**PrintAction.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendoreName\RmaPdfPrint\Controller\Rma;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use VendoreName\Rma\Api\Repository\RmaRepositoryInterface;
use VendoreName\Rma\Api\Service\Rma\RmaManagement\SaveInterface;
use VendoreName\Rma\Helper\Controller\Rma\GuestStrategy;
use VendoreName\Rma\Helper\Controller\Rma\StrategyFactory;
use VendoreName\Rma\Service\Config\FrontendConfig;
use VendoreName\RmaPdfPrint\Block\DownloadRmaPdf;

class PrintAction extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
{
    protected $rmaData;

    private $guestStrategy;
    private $rmaRepository;
    private $rmaSaveManagement;
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        GuestStrategy $guestStrategy,
        RmaRepositoryInterface $rmaRepository,
        SaveInterface $rmaSaveManagement,
        Registry $registry,
        StrategyFactory $strategyFactory,
        Session $customerSession,
        FrontendConfig $frontendConfig,
        DownloadRmaPdf $rmaData
    ) {
        $this->guestStrategy     = $guestStrategy;
        $this->rmaRepository     = $rmaRepository;
        $this->rmaSaveManagement = $rmaSaveManagement;
        $this->registry          = $registry;
        $this->rmaData           = $rmaData;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $rma = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $this->registry->register('current_rma', $rma);
        $this->rmaSaveManagement->markAsReadForCustomer($rma);
        $pdf = $this->rmaData->getPdf($rma); // Here We set RMA Data
        $pdf->render();
        $pdfData = $pdf->render();

        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=result.pdf');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

        echo $pdfData;
    }
}
```

> Must Open link whole code are in the file