# Magento 2: Convert HTML code into PDF file and Download?

Tags: magento2, module, pdf

In my custom module, I have HTML code and I want to convert HTML code into PDF and after conversion download PDF.

Please suggest me Magento-2 default functions or classes for Create PDF and Download.

Comment: Please help me on this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place below code in your module controller for create and download PDF in Magento-2 and for [more information follow this link](https://devzone.zend.com/1064/zend_pdf-tutorial/)

```
$pdf = new \Zend_Pdf(); //Create new PDF file

$page = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);

$pdf->pages[] = $page; 

$page->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 20);  //Set Font 

$page->drawText('Hello world!', 100, 510); 

$pdfData = $pdf->render(); // Get PDF document as a string 

header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=result.pdf"); 

header("Content-type: application/x-pdf"); 

echo $pdfData;
```

Comment: where in this code , html is being inserted , cannot understand

Answer (score 2):

You Can also create generate pdf programmatically using below code :

Vendor/Module/registration.php put below code.

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

add the module.xml file in Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml put below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

add Controller file in Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php  put below code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context            $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
    ) {
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * to generate pdf
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
        $pdf->pages[] = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $page = $pdf->pages[0]; // this will get reference to the first page.
        $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $style->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0,0,0));
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);
        $style->setFont($font,15);
        $page->setStyle($style);
        $width = $page->getWidth();
        $hight = $page->getHeight();
        $x = 30;
        $pageTopalign = 850; //default PDF page height
        $this->y = 850 - 100; //print table row from page top – 100px
        //Draw table header row’s
        $style->setFont($font,16);
        $page->setStyle($style);
        $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y + 10, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y +70, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);
        $style->setFont($font,15);
        $page->setStyle($style);
        $page->drawText(__("Cutomer Details"), $x + 5, $this->y+50, 'UTF-8');
        $style->setFont($font,11);
        $page->setStyle($style);
        $page->drawText(__("Name : %1", "John Smith"), $x + 5, $this->y+33, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(__("Email : %1","test@example.com"), $x + 5, $this->y+16, 'UTF-8');

        $style->setFont($font,12);
        $page->setStyle($style);
        $page->drawText(__("PRODUCT NAME"), $x + 60, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(__("PRICE"), $x + 200, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(__("QUANTITY"), $x + 310, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(__("TOTAL"), $x + 440, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');

        $style->setFont($font,10);
        $page->setStyle($style);
        $add = 9;
        $page->drawText("$10.00", $x + 210, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(5, $x + 330, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText("$50.00", $x + 470, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
        $pro = "ABC product";
        $page->drawText($pro, $x + 65, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y -62, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y + 10, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);
        $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y -62, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y - 100, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);
        $style->setFont($font,15);
        $page->setStyle($style);
        $page->drawText(__("Total : %1", "$50.00"), $x + 435, $this->y-85, 'UTF-8');
        $style->setFont($font,10);
        $page->setStyle($style);
        $page->drawText(__("ABC Footer example"), ($page->getWidth()/2)-50, $this->y-200);

        $fileName = 'example.pdf';

        $this->fileFactory->create(
           $fileName,
           $pdf->render(),
           \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR, // this pdf will be saved in var directory with the name example.pdf
           'application/pdf'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest Dompdf to convert HTML to PDF in magento2. This is an awesome library used for conversion. [Follow this link](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) for more information.

Comment: @BornCoder please assist me . how to use with magento2

Comment: @AskBytes : what problem are you facing?

Comment: i want step by step procedures for using Dompdf for invoice printing

Answer (score 0):

**step 1 (install lib)**

```
composer require setasign/fpdf:1.8.1 && composer require setasign/fpdi:2.0 && composer require knplabs/knp-snappy && composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 "0.12.4"
```

**step 2**

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Helper\DPD;

require_once(BP.'/vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once(BP.'/vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/autoload.php');
use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;


class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
public function getLabel( $shipmentId, $orderModel, $parcelNumbers ){

            try{
                $accountNumber = 'testing;
                $headers = array(
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Accept: text/html',
                    'GeoClient: account/' . $accountNumber,
                    'GeoSession: ' . $loginSession);
                $apiUrl = "URL here";
                $content = $this->apiCall($headers,$apiUrl, 'GET');
               
//                 echo $content;exit;
                $directory = 'path to save the file';
                $fileName = $orderModel->getIncrementId() .".pdf";
                try {

                    $snappy = new Pdf(\h4cc\WKHTMLToPDF\WKHTMLToPDF::PATH);
                    $FileNAme = $fileName;
                    $fullUrl = $directory . '/' . $FileNAme;
                    if (file_exists($fullUrl)) {
                        unlink($fullUrl);
                    }
                    $snappy->generateFromHtml($content, $fullUrl, array(
                        'orientation' => 'portrait',
                        'page-width' => '107',
                        'dpi' => 12399,
                        'page-height' => '107',
                        'lowquality' => false,
                        'margin-bottom'  => 0,
                        'margin-left'  => 0,
                        'margin-right'  => 0,
                        'margin-top'  => 0,
                        'zoom' => 1.23,
                        'encoding' => 'utf-8'
                    ));

                    $pdf = new FPDI('L','mm', array(107,107));
                    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($fullUrl); //the original file
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++) {
                        $pageformat = array('Rotate' => 180);
                        $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);
                        $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tpage);
                        // get original page orientation
                        $orientation = 'portrait';
                        $pdf->AddPage($orientation, '', 180);
                        $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);
                    }
                    $pdf->Output($fullUrl, "F");
                    $data = file_get_contents($fullUrl);

                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    $Error = "Error Occur while getting the label from API : " . $e->getMessage();
                    $this->dpdErrors[] = $Error;
                    $this->mbDpdLog($Error);
                }

            }catch( exception $e ){
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Zend_Loader;

class GetPdfData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $dir;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->initializePDF();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(\VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\YouBlockName::class)
            ->setTemplate("VendoreName_ModuleName::YourFileName.phtml");

        $pdfData = [];
        $pdfData["body_data"] = $block->toHtml();
        $config = [
            'mode' => 'utf-8',
            'format' => 'A4',
            'default_font_size' => 10,
            'default_font' => "dejavusans",
            'margin_left' => 1.5,
            'margin_right' => 1.5,
            'margin_top' => 1.5,
            'margin_bottom' => 1.5,
            'allow_charset_conversion' => true,
            'orientation' => 'P',
            'showBarcodeNumbers' => false,
            'tempDir' => $this->dir->getPath('var'),
        ];
        $pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($config);
        $pdf->WriteHTML(html_entity_decode($pdfData["body_data"]));
        $outputData = $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'D'); // D , F , S
    }

    /**
     * Initialization of mpdf library
     */
    protected function initializePDF()
    {
        error_reporting(0);

        $path = $this->dir->getRoot() . "/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/";

        $this->pdf = $path . 'Mpdf.php';

        //include_once $this->pdf;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pdf, null, true);

        $this->config = $path . 'Config/ConfigVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->config;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->config, null, true);

        $this->ucdn = $path . 'Ucdn.php';

        // require_once $this->ucdn;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->ucdn, null, true);

        $this->defaultCss = $path . 'Css/DefaultCss.php';

        // require_once $this->defaultCss;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->defaultCss, null, true);

        $this->sizeConvertor = $path . 'SizeConverter.php';

        // require_once $this->sizeConvertor;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->sizeConvertor, null, true);

        $this->colorconverter = $path . 'Color/ColorConverter.php';

        // require_once $this->colorconverter;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->colorconverter, null, true);

        $this->gradient = $path . 'Gradient.php';

        // require_once $this->gradient;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->gradient, null, true);

        $this->tableOfContents = $path . 'TableOfContents.php';

        // require_once $this->tableOfContents;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->tableOfContents, null, true);

        $this->cache = $path . 'Cache.php';

        // require_once $this->cache;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->cache, null, true);

        $this->fontCache = $path . 'Fonts/FontCache.php';

        // require_once $this->fontCache;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->fontCache, null, true);

        $this->fontsFileFinder = $path . 'Fonts/FontFileFinder.php';

        // require_once $this->fontsFileFinder;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->fontsFileFinder, null, true);

        $this->cssManager = $path . 'CssManager.php';

        // require_once $this->cssManager;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->cssManager, null, true);

        $this->otl = $path . 'Otl.php';

        // require_once $this->otl;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->otl, null, true);

        $this->form = $path . 'Form.php';

        // require_once $this->form;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->form, null, true);

        $this->hyphenator = $path . 'Hyphenator.php';

        // require_once $this->hyphenator;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->hyphenator, null, true);

        $this->tag = $path . 'Tag.php';

        // require_once $this->tag;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->tag, null, true);

        $this->namedcolors = $path . 'Color/NamedColors.php';

        // require_once $this->namedcolors;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->namedcolors, null, true);

        $this->pageformat = $path . 'PageFormat.php';

        // require_once $this->pageformat;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pageformat, null, true);

        $this->fontVariables = $path . 'Config/FontVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->fontVariables;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->fontVariables, null, true);

        $this->textvars = $path . 'Css/TextVars.php';

        // require_once $this->textvars;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->textvars, null, true);

        $this->border = $path . 'Css/Border.php';

        // require_once $this->border;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->border, null, true);

        $this->logcontext = $path . 'Log/Context.php';

        // require_once $this->logcontext;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->logcontext, null, true);

        $this->ttfontfile = $path . 'TTFontFile.php';

        // require_once $this->ttfontfile;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->ttfontfile, null, true);

        $this->destination = $path . 'Output/Destination.php';

        // require_once $this->destination;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->destination, null, true);

        $this->mpdfexception = $path . 'MpdfException.php';

        // require_once $this->mpdfexception;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->mpdfexception, null, true);

        $this->metricsgenerator = $path . 'Fonts/MetricsGenerator.php';

        // require_once $this->metricsgenerator;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->metricsgenerator, null, true);

        $this->GlyphOperator = $path . 'Fonts/GlyphOperator.php';

        // require_once $this->GlyphOperator;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->GlyphOperator, null, true);

        $this->barcode = $path . 'Barcode.php';

        // require_once $this->barcode;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->barcode, null, true);

    }

}
```

**Note: MPdf is installing via composer require mpdf/mpdf command which placed into the vendor directory.**