# Magento 2 | How can I get the invoice pdf programatically?

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf

I'm currently creating a module which should send the invoice pdf via eMail to a customer.

How can I get the invoice pdf programatically?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create **Sendmail.php** file at `app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/Controller/Index` and write the following code in it.

```
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;
 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
 
class Sendmail extends Action
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_QUOTE_SENDER = 'emailcustom/general/sender';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_QUOTE_NOTIFICATION = 'emailcustom/general/template';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_EMAIL = 'emailcustom/general/reciver';
    

    protected $  scopeConfig;
    protected $_modelStoreManagerInterface;
    protected $  inlineTranslation;
    protected $_logLoggerInterface;
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $_mediaDirectory;
    
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $modelStoreManagerInterface,
        ScopeConfigInterface $configScopeConfigInterface,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        LoggerInterface $logLoggerInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $quoteTransportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
    )
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $configScopeConfigInterface;
        $this->_modelStoreManagerInterface = $modelStoreManagerInterface;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_logLoggerInterface = $logLoggerInterface;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $quoteTransportBuilder;
        $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        try
        {
            $customerName = " Customer Name  : Test";
            $email = "test@gmail.com";
            // Send Mail To Admin For This
            $pdfContent = $this->createPdf($customerName,$email);
                        
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $storeScope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                     ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_QUOTE_NOTIFICATION, $storeScope))
                     ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend','store' => Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,])
                     ->setTemplateVars(['customerName'  => $customerName,'customerEmail'  => $email,])
                     ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_QUOTE_SENDER, $storeScope))
                     ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_EMAIL, $storeScope))
                     ->addAttachment($pdfContent)
                     ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
 
            $response = "success";            
            $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $resultJson->setData($response);
            return $resultJson;
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            $this->_logLoggerInterface->debug($e->getMessage());
                                                
            $response = "error";  
            $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $resultJson->setData($response);
            return $resultJson; 
        }
    }
    public function getLogo($page)
    {
        $image = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('sales/identity/logo',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,$this->_modelStoreManagerInterface->getStore()->getId());
                
        $imagePath = '/sales/store/logo/' . $image;
         
        if($this->_mediaDirectory->isFile($imagePath))
        {
            $image = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($imagePath));
            $top = 830;
            $width = $image->getPixelWidth();
            $height = $image->getPixelHeight();
            $y1 = $top - $height;
            $y2 = $top;
            $x1 = 25;
            $x2 = $x1 + $width;
            $page->drawImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
        }
        return $page;
    }
    public function createPdf( $customername,$customeremail)
    {
        $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf(); //Create new PDF file
        $page = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $pdf->pages[] = $page;
        $top = 810;
        $left = 50;
        $page->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 20);  //Set Font
        $page->drawText("Heading", $left+200, $top-110,'UTF-8');

        $page->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 14);  //Set Font
        $page->drawText("Customer Name : ".$customername, $left, $top-140,'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText("Customer Email : ".$customeremail, $left, $top-165,'UTF-8');
        
        $topstart = 500;
        $leftStart = 70;
        $addHeight = 25;
        $this->getLogo($page);
        $page->drawLine(25, $topstart+70, 550, $topstart+70);       
                                                                                                                                                                    
        $page->drawLine(25, $topstart-100, 550, $topstart-100);
        $page->drawText("Thank you" , 250, $topstart-120,'UTF-8');            
        $page->drawLine(25, $topstart-130, 550, $topstart-130);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.1, 0.1, 0.1));
        $page->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 9);
        
        $footer = 10;
        $page->drawText("Company Name", 70, $footer, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText("Tel: +91 123456", 230, $footer, 'UTF-8');

        $pdfData = $pdf->render(); // Get PDF document as a string
        
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=pdfresult.pdf");
        
        header("Content-type: application/x-pdf");
        return $pdfData;
    }
}
```

Then, You need to create another file at `app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/Model/Mail` and add below code inside the file.

```
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Mail;
 
class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    /**
    * @param Api\AttachmentInterface $attachment
    */
    public function addAttachment($pdfString)
    {
        $this->message->createAttachment($pdfString,'application/pdf',\Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,\Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,'attachment.pdf');
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function clearHeader($headerName)
    {
        if (isset($this->_headers[$headerName])) {
            unset($this->_headers[$headerName]);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Rohan How can I test it.. i used this but no output..

Comment: Hi, @Rohan Hapani. In your Sendmail.php you are using \`Magecomp\Emailquotepro\Model\Mail\TransportBuilder $quoteTransportBuilder`. This seems to be 3rd party code, do I really need this here? Thx

Comment: It's typo. I updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Easy Way

There are already extensions for this.

FREE - **Fooman Email Attachments**
https://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-email-attachments-m2.html

PAID - **Magento 2 PDF Invoice by Mageplaza**
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-pdf-invoice-extension/?utm_source=mageplaza&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=print-pdf-invoice

### Hard Way

If you want to to do it programmatically then i recommend checking the below links

https://webkul.com/blog/generate-pdf-programmatically-magento2/

[Magento2: How to create a PDF in a custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112193/magento2-how-to-create-a-pdf-in-a-custom-module)

Hope i helped. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your module **Vendor_Module**
2. Create route **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
        <router id="standard">
            <route id="myroute" frontName="myroute">
                <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
            </route>
        </router>
    </config>
```

3. Create front controller **app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Getpdf/Invoice.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Getpdf;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice as PdfInvoice;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;


class Invoice implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    const SELECTED_PARAM = 'id';

    protected FileFactory $fileFactory;
    protected DateTime $dateTime;
    protected PdfInvoice $pdfInvoice;
    protected RequestInterface $request;
    protected RedirectInterface $redirect;
    protected ManagerInterface $messageManager;
    protected ResultFactory $resultFactory;
    protected CollectionFactory $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param DateTime $dateTime
     * @param FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param PdfInvoice $pdfInvoice
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param RedirectInterface $redirect
     * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param ResultFactory $resultFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        DateTime          $dateTime,
        FileFactory       $fileFactory,
        PdfInvoice        $pdfInvoice,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        RequestInterface  $request,
        RedirectInterface $redirect,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        ResultFactory $resultFactory
    )
    {
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
        $this->pdfInvoice = $pdfInvoice;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();

            $invoiceId = $this->request->getParam(self::SELECTED_PARAM);
            $filterIds = $invoiceId ? [$invoiceId] : [];
            $collection->addFieldToFilter(
                $collection->getResource()->getIdFieldName(),
                ['in' => $filterIds]
            );

            $pdf = $this->pdfInvoice->getPdf($collection);
            $fileContent = ['type' => 'string', 'value' => $pdf->render(), 'rm' => true];

            return $this->fileFactory->create(
                sprintf('invoice%s.pdf', $this->dateTime->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s')),
                $fileContent,
                DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                'application/pdf'
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());            
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
}
```

4. Now you are ready to use this controller. Just create a link and put there href with a path to our controller  (In some cases it is a good idea to use  **Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info** as a class to your block for getting order like  `$order = $block->getOrder();`)
5. Having an order information you can get invoices in your .phtml file

```
<?php foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice):?>
    <a href="<?= $block->getUrl('myroute/getpdf/invoice', ['id' => $invoice->getId()]);?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(__('Invoice (PDF)')); ?></a>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found this link, it works great
[Free Extension to download Invoice PDF](https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/download-invoice-pdf-from-customer-account-free-magento-extension/)