# magento2 product attribute name and value generate in pdf format on detail page?

Tags: magento2, pdf, download

getSkU(); ?>

getName(); ?>

getPrice(); ?>

getShortDescription(); ?>

getDescription(); ?>

Download Data sheet

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/358266/82670

Comment: And  this one also : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112193/magento2-how-to-create-a-pdf-in-a-custom-module

Comment: explain in details what you have try and which issue you are facing?

Comment: i have try below link pass controller action but pdf failed every time  <a href="digital\customFiled\controller\index\index" download>Download Data sheet</a>